# Getting all likes from a specific user on a news wall with fewer graph API calls

Tags: javascript, api, graph, facebook

Right now, my solution counting likes of a specific user is

1. Starting a recursive call on the "/{user-id}/posts" edge
2. Iterate through all posts
3. On each post iterate through each like on the likes edge

If someone knows a better, easier way with less graph API calls necessary, please let me know!

```
/*
*
*   Count my_user_id likes in wall of user "123"
*
*   ex: url = /123/posts
*   
*   setTimeout to avoid exceed api level rate limit, code 613
*/

function findMyLikes(url,my_user_id,count,callback) {
    console.log(url);
    FB.api(url, function (response) {
        if (response.data) {
            response.data.forEach(function (post) {
                //console.log(post);
                if (post.likes) {
                    post.likes.data.forEach(function (like) {
                        if (like.id == my_user_id) {
                            count++;
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        }

        if (response.paging && response.paging.next) {
            setTimeout(function() {findMyLikes(response.paging.next,my_user_id,count,callback)},1000);
        } else {
            callback(count);
        }
    });

};
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Do know that reviewers can review other aspects of your code.

Comment: Hi Marc, thanks, I'm glad for any advise improving my code.

Comment: Would this help to simplify your code : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.1/object/likes

Comment: @konijn you are referencing the likes edge which i'm currently using

Answer (score 1):

Interesting / fun question.

I don't think there is much to improve there to reduce the API call count.

From a once over, these are some things you might want to look at:

- `forEach` is still slower than the good old `for` loop, not sure that matters for you.
- Don't use `console.log` in production code
- Don't keep commented out code in production code
- Does it make sense to keep comparing to `my_user_id` if you already found a match ? It is not like you could like the same post twice ? (One more (better) argument to not use `forEach` here)
- `my_user_id` -> `myUserId` -> `id` , always apply lowerCamelCase plus *keep it simple*

Not relevant after comment

- You say you are using the *likes edge* in your comment, so you might want to mention that in your example `ex: url = /123/posts/likes` ?
- If `post.likes` is not set while using the likes edge, then something serious is going on , consider an early 'return callback(count);`
- Same thing for `if (response.data)`

Comment: - the url has to target the posts edge, because I'm collecting likes of a object, in this case posts. in the next step I loop over all posts found and check them for likes. 
- there exists two kind of likes: 'object/likes' and 'user/likes'. 'user/likes' refers to "All the pages this person has liked" and 'object/likes' refers to "All the likes on this post". maybe you mixed up them?
- the likes edge on objects may return an array of user objects. To sum my likes for this particular friend, I have to check if my user_id is present in the array.

Comment: Right, you got me confused because you told me you used the likes edge, so I thought you used something like "/{user-id}/posts/likes"

Comment: yes, I'm working with the likes edge of objects 'object-id/likes', not with the likes edge of users 'user-id/likes'